# How can I simulate class/method friendship in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, friend

I remember (barely) in C++ that you could create friend classes or methods, capable of accessing your private members. Frankly, I never found that feature particularly useful.

Now I am using Ruby for a game development framework. I'm making a simple node system (a node can contain other children nodes, and have a parent node).

My `Node` class has `#add_child(child)`. The thing is, when `A` node gets a child `B` node, I need to set `B`'s `@parent` reference to point to `A`. So inside `#add_child(child)` I have this call:

```
child.set_parent(self)
```

Now `B`'s `@parent` variable points to `A`. And this works just fine.

But, `#set_parent(parent)` **is only meant to be used for this specific scenario**. It must only be called when `#add_child(child)` is called. If I used `#set_parent(parent)` out of context, the node system may break.

Now I do find the class/method friendship thing useful. If I could make `#set_parent(parent)` only usable by `#add_child(child)`,  my system wouldn't break if some random programmer decided to call `#set_parent(parent)` by themselves.

From a few searches it doesn't seem like Ruby has this feature explicitly.

Does Ruby offer class/method friendship features like C++ does? If not, how else can I work around the described problem?

Comment: Aren't you talking about protected access?

Comment: @vgoff: I guess. Frankly I'm not very familiar with these concepts.

Comment: From [RubyLearning Ruby Access Control](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html) "Protected methods can be invoked only by objects of the defining class and its subclasses. Access is kept within the family. However, usage of protected is limited."

Comment: "If I could make #set_parent(parent) only usable by #add_child(child)" - that's really not what class friendship (in C++) does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Node
  def add_child(child)
    @children << child # or whatever
    child.instance_exec(self) { |parent| set_parent(parent) }
  end
end
```

Inside `instance_exec` you're as if inside the other object, so you can invoke private methods, or even directly set instance variables. `child.instance_exec(self) { |parent| @parent = parent }` would work as well. You could also do `child.send(:set_parent, self)` or `child.instance_variable_set(:parent, self)`, but I think `instance_exec` makes it a bit clearer what you're doing. YMMV. :)

Ruby only nominally protects the insides of its classes, enough that you don't shoot yourself in the foot by accident. But its introspection capabilities are powerful enough that you can access anything from anywhere if you want to.

Comment: If your only goal is to circumvent access restrictions, then there is no need to use any of the `eval`/`exec` family. `send` and `instance_variable_set` are enough.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: True. As soon as I press submit, there's something else I want to write...

Answer (score 1):

There's also the "friend" gem which adds this language feature to ruby: https://github.com/lsegal/friend